# Create loading modal for all of ajax requests except one of them

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this code for showing a modal for ajax requests :

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function () { showLoadingModal(); });
$(document).ajaxError(function () {
    closeLoadingModal();
    alert("error");
});
```

By using this code, i have this modal for all of my requests.
But i want to have do another operations for some of ajax requests.
Whats your idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `ajaxStart`, use `ajaxSend` and filter request depending URL:

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function (event, xhr, options) {
    if(options.url != "requestURLToexclude") showLoadingModal();
})
```